# returning (back) the windows form c++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I want to create multiple forms and when I click the back button it will back to form1. I tried this  [C++/CLI - how to open a new form and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768613/c-cli-how-to-open-a-new-form-and-back) but when I click the button in the form2 to go back to form1 it gets an error. " NullReferenceException was Unhandled"

**Form1**

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

            /* Form1::Hide();
             Form2^ form2 = gcnew Form2();
             form2->ShowDialog();*/


             Form2 ^ frm2 = gcnew Form2();
             frm2->Show();
             this->Hide();
         }
```

**Form2**

```
Form2(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ frm1)
{
    otherform = frm1;
    InitializeComponent();

}

private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e
 {

 this->Hide();
 otherform->Show();   
 }
```

Comment: You have a constructor that takes a Form reference.  You are not using it.  So sure, *otherform* is still nullptr.  Kaboom.

Comment: May be you should call the non-default constructor of `Form2` like this: `Form2 ^ frm2 = gcnew Form2(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the second constructor of `Form2` but you are not using it inside `button1_Click`.

Instead of this:

```
Form2 ^ frm2 = gcnew Form2();
```

Do this:

```
Form2 ^ frm2 = gcnew Form2(this);
```

Comment: "error C3767: 'Multiple_forms::Form2::Form2': candidate function(s) not accessible"      
this is the error when I tried that.

Comment: Have you defined the `Form2(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ frm1)` constructor as `public`?

Comment: I declared it as private

Comment: You are accessing the `Form2` constructor inside a function of class `Form1`. Declare the constructor `public` or else it would not be accessible outside the `Form2` class.