# Windows Forms - go back to first form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I having trouble going back to form1 from form2.

What i'm trying to do:

form1 takes you to form2 when button is click and

form2 takes you to form1 when button is click.

I tried changing `this->Visible = false;` to `this->Close();`on both forms and i get this error

```
1>c:\users\form2.h(172): error C2065: 'form1' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\form2.h(172): error C2065: 'go_form1' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\form2.h(172): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'menu_form'
1>c:\users\form2.h(173): error C2065: 'go_form1' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\form2.h(173): error C2227: left of '->Show' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Form 1

```
#include "form2.h"

private: System::Void start_button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 form2^ go_form2 = gcnew form2();
                 go_form2->Show();
                 this->Visible = false;
             }
```

Form 2

```
#include "form1.h"

    private: System::Void start_button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                     form1^ go_form1 = gcnew form1();
                     go_form1->Show();
                     this->Visible = false;
                 }
```

**Edit:**
I tried doing this [C++/CLI - how to open a new form and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768613/c-cli-how-to-open-a-new-form-and-back) Now it opens second form but in small window with nothing on it

Form2

```
public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form2(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    public:
        Form2(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ form1)
        {
            otherform = form1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;

private: System::Void Button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            this->Hide();
            otherform->Show();
         }
```

Form1

```
private: System::Void button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Form2^ go_form2 = gcnew Form2(this);
             go_form2->Show();
             this->Hide();
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work now. I had commented out `InitializeComponent();`in my constructor